# Python Code only running in Debugging mode

Tags: python-3.x

So I've been working on a script that a co-worker of mine made now i fixed some of his issues but i cannot seem to figure out why it only actually works when i run it in debugging mode in VSC even when i run it from a normal python shell it does not give me the output files that it does when running in debug mode does anyone know why? (Some Links and sensitive company data has been removed)

here is the code:

````
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import urllib3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#______________________________________________________________________________________

#main functie
def Main():

  

    #http request met api account naar de export lijst Rapid7
    urllib3.disable_warnings() #negeert de waarschuwingen van de self signed certificaten
    url = "URL REMOVED"
    r= requests.get(url,verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('REMOVED', 'REMOVED))

    #data opslaan van de http request in csv formaat
    with open('downloaded.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
        csv_file.write(r.content)
    

    #open het input bestand van AD
    Filenameslist = "C:\Robert-Code\ComputerListForRapid7.json" #volledig pad naar het bestand toegevoegd
    with open(Filenameslist) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    #converteer json naar een CSV-besand
    with open("computerlist.csv", "w") as f:
            
        fieldnames = data[3].keys()
        # haal de keys van de 3e regel, want soms is de eerste regel van de sourcefile leeg
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
        

    #Ik gebruik de Pandas module om alleen de kolom "name" van het Rapid7 bestand te krijgen die ik nodig heb.
    # Dan draai ik naam en adres om, zodat de naam in de eerste kolom staat. Hiervoor lees ik de CSV in een dataframe
    dfR7 = pd.read_csv("downloaded.csv")
    titles = list(dfR7.columns)
    titles[0],titles[1] = titles[1],titles[0] #draai om, zodat name in de eerste kolom staat
    dfR7 = dfR7[titles]   # zet de kolommen en data goed in het object
    dfR7.sort_values(["Name"], inplace = True)
    dfR7.drop(columns=["Address","Operating System","Site","Exploits","Malware","Vulnerabilities","Risk","Last Scan","Assessed"], inplace=True)
    dfR7["Name"] = dfR7["Name"].str.split('.').str[0] #strip het domein van het FQDN
    dfR7["Name"] = dfR7["Name"].str.lower() # alles lowercase


    #Pandas module om ook van het AD-betand 1 kolom "name" over te houden in het object dfAD zodat ik later kan vergelijken.
    dfAD = pd.read_csv("computerlist.csv")
    dfAD.drop(columns=["DNSHostName","OperatingSystem","IPAddress", "LastLogon"], inplace= True)
    dfAD["Computer"] = dfAD["Computer"].str.lower()

    #beide objecten opslaan in een csv-bestand deze te vergelijken
    dfR7.to_csv("fr7.csv", index=False)
    dfAD.to_csv("fAD.csv", index=False)

    with open('fr7.csv', 'r') as t1, open('fAD.csv', 'r') as t2:
        fileRapid = t1.readlines()
        fileAD = t2.readlines()

    #de bestanden fr7.csv en fad.csv vergelijken aan de hand van een for loop
    # deze dan opslaan in update.csv
    with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
        for line in fileAD:
            if line not in fileRapid:
                outFile.write(line)

    #hier haal ik weer het oude bestand van AD erbij om deze zometeen te mergen met het net gemaakte update.csv bestand
    # zodat ik alle nuttige kolommen weer heb
    dfAD = pd.read_csv("computerlist.csv")
    dfAD["Computer"] = dfAD["Computer"].str.lower()
    dfAD.to_csv("f1AD.csv", index=False)

    # merge functie van de Pandas module
    data1 = pd.read_csv('update.csv')
    data2 = pd.read_csv("f1AD.csv")
    output1 = pd.merge(data1, data2,
                        on='Computer', 
                        how='inner')

    #opslaan naar TotalresultsAD.csv
    output1.to_csv("totaldifferenceAD_R7.csv", index =False)

    #met de datetime module maak ik een variabele: time met de dag van vandaag minus 30 dagen
    time = datetime.today() - timedelta(60)

    "lees 2 x het bestand in"
    dfgood = pd.read_csv("totaldifferenceAD_R7.csv")
    dfbad = pd.read_csv("totaldifferenceAD_R7.csv")

    #dit outputbestand geeft de assets weer die een LastLogon hebben recenter dan 30 dagen geleden
    dfgood['LastLogon'] = pd.to_datetime(dfgood['LastLogon'], errors = 'coerce') #errors = 'coerce' zorgt ervoor dat de foutieve waarden in de kolom LastLogon worden genegeerd
    dfgood.sort_values(["LastLogon"], inplace = True)
    dfnew = (dfgood['LastLogon'] >= time)
    dfnew = dfgood.loc[dfnew]

    #dit outputbestand geeft de assets weer die een LastLogon hebben ouder dan 30 dagen geleden
    dfbad['LastLogon'] = pd.to_datetime(dfbad['LastLogon'], errors = 'coerce') #errors = 'coerce' zorgt ervoor dat de foutieve waarden in de kolom LastLogon worden genegeerd
    dfbad.sort_values(["LastLogon"], inplace = True)
    newdf2 = (dfbad['LastLogon'] < time)
    newdf2 = dfbad.loc[newdf2]
    #wegschrijven uiteindelijke bestanden
    dfnew.to_csv("newer_than_60_days.csv",index =False)
    newdf2.to_csv("older_than_60_days.csv",index =False)

    #opschonen van de bestanden
    os.remove("FAD.csv")
    os.remove("fr7.csv")
    os.remove("computerlist.csv")
    os.remove("downloaded.csv")
    os.remove("f1AD.csv")
    os.remove("update.csv")

if __name__=="__main__":
    Main() ```

Thanks in advance for any help
````

Comment: What is this (the 3 apostrophes):    Main() ```

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.... the thing is i did not write the code it was written by a intern wich since has left so I'm probably better off rewriting it

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't have a high enough SO reputation, unfortunately I can't simply comment this and need to make it an 'Answer'.

Changing

```
r= requests.get(url,verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('REMOVED', 'REMOVED))
```

to

```
r= requests.get(url,verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('REMOVED', 'REMOVED'))
```

will get the syntax highlighting all fixed up and may make it easier for someone smarter than me to assist you :)

Something that I've previously come across (primarily with web scraping packages) were functions that didn't play nicely with relative paths - perhaps changing them to absolute paths using `os.path.abspath(".....")` may help? It's a stab in the dark so that this 'Answer' actually has a potentially useful element to it, but may be an adjustment worth exploring.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).